# SVG Click Handling Inconsistent With Displayed Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, svg

I am building a web based, world domination game. The backbone of the game is a three level zoomable map of thirty-eight territories.

[image: Zooming Map]

I built the map with SVG paths. The global view has a widescreen aspect ratio. When displaying the map on a square screen, for the sake of aesthetics, the entire SVG must be centered vertically using an animation tag. I've gotten the centering to work perfectly, the part I don't understand comes in when I click to zoom the map. It seems as though for the purposes of clicking, the map is a few (about 25) pixels above where it is displayed. For example, if I were to click on the grey background slightly above Russia, it would zoom me to the Asian continent. It seems more interesting to me when I consider the fact that I use transforms on every path for territorial and continental zoom levels, and the same problem does not occur.

The HTML looks as such:

```
<div class="test1"  width="100%" height="100%">
    <div id="renderedSprites"></div>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="continentFilter" class="filter"></div>
    <div id="territoryFilter" class="filter"></div>
    <svg
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    class="territoryImage" 
    id="continentalSVG"></svg>
    <svg
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    class="territoryImage" 
    id="territorialSVG"></svg>
    <%= render partial: "images" %>
</div>
```

The images partial contains the global SVG, which is too long to show but follows this format:

```
 <svg
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    class="territoryImage" 
    id="globalSVG">

   <g>
  <path
 class="continentName"
   id="territoryName"

     d="..."

     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
 </g>

37 More paths and animations...

</svg>
```

The zooming JS is simple and pretty much irrelevant. I just clone the paths for the desired piece of the map into the proper SVG for that level. I then display that SVG at a higher z-index and put a filter or set of filters in between displayed levels. Here it is though, anyways (sorry it's so packed and disgusting):

```
var zoomLevel = ["global","globe"];
//renderObject("encampment",zoomLevel);
//renderObject("fort",zoomLevel);
$(".territoryImage").click( function(e) {
if ($(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY)).is("path") == true) {
    if (zoomLevel[0] == "global") { 
        var continent = $(".".concat($(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY)).attr("class")))
        for (i = 0; i < continent.length; i++) {
            $("#continentalSVG").append($(continent[i]).parent().clone())
        }

        var box = $("#continentalSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect()
        var newScaleFactor
        if (box.width/$(window).width() > box.height/$(window).height()) {
            newScaleFactor = ($("#background").width()*parseFloat($("#continentalSVG").children("g").attr("transform").split(")")[0].replace("scale(","")))/box.width*0.95;
            console.log(newScaleFactor);
        }
        else {
            newScaleFactor = ($("#background").height()*parseFloat($("#continentalSVG").children("g").attr("transform").split(")")[0].replace("scale(","")))/box.height*0.95;
            console.log(newScaleFactor);
        }
        $("#continentalSVG").children("g").attr("transform","scale(" + newScaleFactor + ")");
        var scaledBox = $("#continentalSVG").offset();
        scaledBox.top = ((scaledBox.top - $("#background").offset().top)/newScaleFactor) - (($("#background").height()/2) - ($("#continentalSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height/2))
        scaledBox.left = ((scaledBox.left - $("#background").offset().left)/newScaleFactor) - (($("#background").width()/2) - ($("#continentalSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width/2))
        $("#continentalSVG").children("g").attr("transform", $("#continentalSVG").children("g").attr("transform") + " translate(" + -1*scaledBox.left + ", " + -1*scaledBox.top + ")")
        $("#continentalSVG").css("z-index","2");
        $("#continentFilter").css("display","inline");
        zoomLevel = ["continental",$("#continentalSVG").children("g").attr("class")];
        //renderObject("encampment",zoomLevel);
        //renderObject("fort",zoomLevel);
    }
    else if (zoomLevel[0] == "continental") {
        var territory = "#" + document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY).id;
        $("#territorialSVG").append($(territory).parent().clone())
        var box = $("#territorialSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var newScaleFactor
        if (box.width/$(window).width() > box.height/$(window).height()) {
            newScaleFactor = ($("#background").width()*parseFloat($("#territorialSVG").children("g").attr("transform").split(")")[0].replace("scale(","")))/box.width*0.95;
        }
        else {
            newScaleFactor = ($("#background").height()*parseFloat($("#territorialSVG").children("g").attr("transform").split(")")[0].replace("scale(","")))/box.height*0.95;
        }
        $("#territorialSVG").children("g").attr("transform","scale(" + newScaleFactor + ")");
        var scaledBox = $("#territorialSVG").offset()
        //console.log(scaledBox)
        scaledBox.top = ((scaledBox.top - $("#background").offset().top)/newScaleFactor) - ($("#background").height() - ($("#territorialSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height))/(newScaleFactor*2)
        scaledBox.left = ((scaledBox.left - $("#background").offset().left)/newScaleFactor) - ($("#background").width() - ($("#territorialSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width))/(newScaleFactor*2)
        //console.log(($("#background").width() - ($("#territorialSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width))/(newScaleFactor*2))
        $("#territorialSVG").children("g").attr("transform", $("#territorialSVG").children("g").attr("transform") + " translate(" + -1*scaledBox.left + ", " + -1*scaledBox.top + ")")
        $("#territorialSVG").css("z-index","4");
        $("#territoryFilter").css("display","inline");
        zoomLevel = ["territorial",territory, zoomLevel[1]];
        //renderObject("encampment",zoomLevel);
        //renderObject("fort",zoomLevel);
    }
}

else {
    if (zoomLevel[0] == "continental") {
        $("#continentalSVG").children().remove();
        $("#continentFilter").css("display","none");
        $("#continentalSVG").css("z-index","-1");
        zoomLevel = ["global","globe"];
        //renderObject("encampment",zoomLevel);
        //renderObject("fort",zoomLevel);
    }
    else if (zoomLevel[0] == "territorial") {
        $("#territorialSVG").children().remove();
        $("#territoryFilter").css("display","none");
        $("#territorialSVG").css("z-index","-1");
        $("#continentalSVG").css("z-index","2");
        zoomLevel = ["continental", zoomLevel[2]];
        //renderObject("encampment",zoomLevel);
        //renderObject("fort",zoomLevel);
    }
}
 });
```

Here is the relevant part:

```
function setOriginalZoom() {

//this first part scales all the SVG's as well as the background, the filters, and a div I use for sprites
$(".territoryImage").attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + $(window).width()*0.95 + " " + $(window).height()*0.95);
$(".territoryImage").attr("width", $(".territoryImage").attr("viewBox").split(" ")[2]);
$(".territoryImage").attr("height", $(".territoryImage").attr("viewBox").split(" ")[3]);

$("#background").css("width", $(".territoryImage").width())
$("#renderedSprites").css("height", $(".territoryImage").height())
$("#renderedSprites").css("width", $(".territoryImage").width())
$("#background").css("height", $(".territoryImage").height())
$(".filter").css("width", $(".territoryImage").width())
$(".filter").css("height", $(".territoryImage").height())
$("g").attr("transform", "scale(" + $(".territoryImage").attr("viewBox").split(" ")[2]/3508 + ")")

//this part vertically centers the global SVG. The part that seems to trip things up.
$("#globalSVG").children("g").attr("transform", $("#globalSVG").children("g").attr("transform") + " translate(0 " + (($("#background").height()/2) - ($("#globalSVG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height/2) + ($("#globalSVG").offset().top - $("#background").offset().top))/(($(".territoryImage").attr("viewBox").split(" ")[2]/3508)*2) + ")")
}
```

I call this function on page load, and it centers all of the displayed elments. It also scales the SVG's for the global view. The last bit I commented out, was written to vertically center the map.

It has occurred to me that the way I listen for clicks on the map may be responsible for the bug. This piece of code, included in the zooming section above, is what i'm talking about:

```
  $(".territoryImage").click( function(e) {
    if ($(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY)).is("path") == true) {
```

I wrote it that way because the simpler way,

```
$("path").click( function() {...});
```

would fire whenever someone clicks on the SVG. For whatever reason that solution registered the path as being the defined size of the SVG (in terms of height and width attributes which I set to a percent of the window size), while the other implementation only fired when a filled part of the path was clicked.

Now if anyone can figure this out, I would really appreciate it. If you have any questions, really please ask I'll respond asap.

Thanks,

-Alex

Comment: Can you try simplifying your example down to just the bare minimum required to demonstrate the incorrect location issue?  It is probably a difference between SVG coordinates and page/element coordinates, but there is far too much else going on here to easily identify the problem.

Comment: You're definitely right. I'll see if I can reproduce the error. In a jsfiddle.